# my bank just sent a statement titled: Banking Done Different

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, word-order, predicative-complements, flat-adverbs

Is it ever correct to write Banking Done Different?  I am surprised to find this printed at the top of my savings account statement

Comment: In what jurisdiction is your bank located? If it were in the UK, I would choose another bank: if they can't get English grammar right, what else might they get wrong?

Comment: They're trying to be hip. Doesn't work :(